# File formatting with Regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am trying to split a string into multiple matches, each containing 'name', 'attributes' and 'files' (files only applies to a file with the directory attribute)

The string I'm trying to format: (I'm using the Hex-edit program as a test folder)

```
Hex Edit\ 1pÝó/Õ\<changelog.txt\ RÖ©òó/Õ ð`s7bÆÔ%ªòó/Õ        <      \HxD32.exe\ %ovòó/Õ ð‚fNcÆÔ­ÿ—òó/Õ<      Þ     \HxD64.exe\ ¤M˜òó/Õ ð‚fNcÆÔ:Ùžòó/Õ)     †e"     \license.txt\ “Lªòó/Õ ðõhÿªÔ“Lªòó/Õ¯?     c      \readme.txt\ ·&Ÿòó/Õ ðËóyÿªÔp°©òó/Õ„?     ¦
      \Settings\ IRýòó/Õ\<HxD Hex Editor.ini\ ÉÌ"ô/Õ ôeìÔ)3ÖôeìÔ)3Ö¸Ž?     õ      \HxD Hex Editor.lang\ yýòó/Õ yýòó/Õyýòó/Õ­•?     ”       \>>
```

Currently I am using `(?<name>.+?)\\(?<attributes>.{10}( .{32})*?)\\(?<files>(<(?:[^<>]*|(?<open>\<)|(?<-open>\>))+(?(open)(?!))>)*)`

The way the file is formatted:

filename`\`attributes`\`files

attributes can either be `.{10}\s.{32}` or `.{10}` followed by the `\`.

There isn't always files but if there is then files would be `<` + more files (recursive, can go to infinity) + `>`.

What I was hoping this Regex would respond with:

```
Name: Hex Edit
Attributes:  1pÝó/Õ
Files: <changelog.txt\ RÖ©òó/Õ ð`s7bÆÔ%ªòó/Õ        <      \HxD32.exe\ %ovòó/Õ ð‚fNcÆÔ­ÿ—òó/Õ<      Þ     \HxD64.exe\ ¤M˜òó/Õ ð‚fNcÆÔ:Ùžòó/Õ)     †e"     \license.txt\ “Lªòó/Õ ðõhÿªÔ“Lªòó/Õ¯?     c      \readme.txt\ ·&Ÿòó/Õ ðËóyÿªÔp°©òó/Õ„?     ¦
      \Settings\ IRýòó/Õ\<HxD Hex Editor.ini\ ÉÌ"ô/Õ ôeìÔ)3ÖôeìÔ)3Ö¸Ž?     õ      \HxD Hex Editor.lang\ yýòó/Õ yýòó/Õyýòó/Õ­•?     ”       \>>
```

For each match that I returned, if it had no files I would add it to a treeview otherwise I would perform the same Regex on it (until there is none left, eventually making a treeview that has all the files in it).

I have been attempting this for just over two hours now and still have not gotten any closer with my current attempt being `(?<name>[^\\/:*?<>"|]+?)\\(?<attributes>.{10}( .{32})*?)\\(?<files>\<(?>\<(?<c>)|[^<>]+|\>(?<-c>))*(?(c)(?!))\>)`.

The Regex needs to be .net compatible.

Sorry for poor explaination, I am unsure how to word this aswell as it being my first post.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
            string input = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);
            string pattern = @"^(?'name'[^\\]+)\\(?'attribute'[^\\]+)\\(?'files'.*)";

            Match match = Regex.Match(input,pattern);

            string name = match.Groups["name"].Value;
            string attribute = match.Groups["attribute"].Value;
            string files = match.Groups["files"].Value;
```